# can I pass some data using the pthread condition variable in a Wrapper Facade class?

Tags: c++, multithreading, design-patterns, pthreads

I have one pthread processing data from a circular buffer. when it finishes, I signal another thread that it can now process the buffer. So the basic architecture is 2 pthreads processing data in a serial fashion. The 2nd thread is in a loop which blocks like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(pMutex);
pthread_cond_wait(pCondition, pMutex);
pthread_mutex_unlock(pMutex);
```

After my 1st thread finishes processing a particular buffer, it signals the 2nd thread like this:

```
pthread_mutex_lock(m_pEncodeLeftMutex);
pthread_cond_signal(&m_cvEncodeLeft);
pthread_mutex_unlock(m_pEncodeLeftMutex);
```

This all seems to be working just fine.

Now I am trying to learn about C++ patterns so I want to migrate this code to C++. The pattern I am playing with first (since it is the simplest) is the Wrapper Facade pattern. So I want to use a Wrapper Facade for the mutex/condition variable. Here is what I have for the condition variable:

```
class ConditionVariable
{
    public:
        ConditionVariable(class Mutex &);
        ~ConditionVariable();
```

`inline int waitForCondition() { 
        pthread_cond_wait(&m_tCondition, m_tMutex.m_pMutex); 
        return m_nPassedData; 
    }
    inline void signalCondition(int x) { 
        pthread_cond_signal(&m_tCondition); 
        m_nPassedData = x; 
    }

private:
    // by defining the copy ctor, the assigmnent opterator, and default ctor
    // as private, this will disable copying, assignment, and invalid use
    ConditionVariable(const ConditionVariable &);
    void operator= (const ConditionVariable &);
    ConditionVariable();

    int                     m_nPassedData;
    pthread_cond_t          m_tCondition;
    class Mutex             &m_tMutex;`

};

I want to pass the circular buffer index that was processed by the 1st thread to the 2nd thread.My question is about the data passed this way. Is the m_nPassedData protected by the mutex? If the 2nd pthread takes extra long processing the buffer and thus releasing the mutex, will the 1st pthread block since it cannot get the mutex?

Comment: Why not learn c++11 thread model instead of using pthread

Comment: Last year I purchased the 2nd edition of The C++ Standard Library by Nicolai Josuttis which covers C++11 threads. I have used the 1st edition tons and it has been very helpful. I guess I had better dust off the 2nd edition and actually use it.  :-)   Thanks for the suggestion.